# How do I jump to a CSS class/ID in the .css file from Dreamweaver's Code view?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

Here's the situation.  I'm working in Dreamweaver.  Let's say I have 5 different .css files containing various classes and ID's.  And let's say I'm editing index.html in Code view (which is basically just a text editor). And then let's say I've found in the code a CSS class that I want to see the code for.  Or in other words, I want to "jump to" or "go to" the declaration of that class in it's .css page.

Is there a way to do that in Dreamweaver?  It's super annoying right now to see the class name in the Code view, then have to click on each .css page, and then manually search for that class to find out where it lives in order to edit it.

I'm also open to other software packages similar to Dreamweaver that make this easier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Alt+Click on the class to open the "code navigator" popup. There you can see the styles which are applied for the clicked element. Clicking on the selector in the popup opens the css source file for the selector you want to investigate.

Another way is to click on the element with the ID or class and press Shift+F11. This will open the "CSS Styles" window. There there is a a list of rules under the heading "Summary of Selection".

Comment: Thanks.  For some reason though, it always only shows the ID's associated with what I selected, and not the classes.  It also only shows the ID's coming from global.css (the primary .css file, and 1 of 5 .css files).  Any ideas?

Comment: Related to my above secondary question, it may be because I nested the other 4 .css files from global.css, whereby index.html only has one css file reference (to global.css).  Perhaps the index.html page in dreamweaver is unaware of the four other pages when in Code Navigator

Comment: @natsturner I don't know if DW is able to show the CSS of imported CSS files from another CSS.

Comment: thanks, yeah, appears not. It would be a great feature to be able to click on a class or ID name from the Code view and then it jumps you directly to the element's source, regardless of where it is (so long as it's in the same web directory)